# readonly check box on simple form can still be updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form, readonly

We use simple_form 2.0.2 in our rails 3.2 app. For some boolean fields, we want to make it readonly in certain situation and does not allow to update. Here is the code in our app:

```
<%= f.input :signed, :label => t('Signed'), :as => :boolean, :readonly => readonly?(@project, 'signed') %>
```

What we find out is that if `:readonly => true`, when mouse is over the field on simple form, there is a little red circle (with a slash in the circle) showing up. However the check box still could be changed and saved. Is there a way to make boolean check box on simple_form read only and can't be updated with :readonly? Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not with `:readonly`, no.

The `readonly` HTML input attribute only prevents the user from changing the value of the field. It doesn't stop them from interacting with it, as clicking on it and toggling the checkmark shows. That only changes the state of the checkbox, whether it's on or off.

The [specs on the readonly attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-readonly) say this:

> **readonly**
>   This Boolean attribute indicates that the user cannot modify the value of the control.

If you don't want them changing the state at all, you may want to use disabled:

> **disabled**
>   This Boolean attribute indicates that the form control is not available for interaction. In particular, the click event will not be dispatched on disabled controls. Also, a disabled control's value isn't submitted with the form.

But since the input is not sent along, the value will be missing. So consider pairing it with a hidden field that actually holds the value.

```
<%= f.input :signed_display, :label => t('Signed'), :as => :boolean, :disabled => true %>
<%= f.input :signed, :as => :hidden, input_html: {value: @project} %>
```

Comment: Not quite understand why disabled field needs to be paired with another hidden attribute, not mentioned that those two attributes are not the same.

Comment: If you disable a field, it won't be sent along if you need to process the form. That's what there is a hidden field that holds the value you do want to send. If you don't need to send it, then you can just show the value instead of showing a disabled checkbox